# My React @media(min-width:992px){ .NewBlogCard{width:50%;} statement has no effect in browser

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, media-queries

I am trying to learn React through a Udemy video and got stuck at the media queries. When I add the given @media(min-width:992px){ .NewBlogCard{width:50%;} statement into my editor and save it, nothing changes in my browser. All three cards still take up the whole screen instead of half of the screen. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Please see code to all my files below. The above statement is in the file called BlogCard.module.css.

```
BlogCard.module.css
.NewBlogCard{
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #CCC;
    background-color: lightblue;
  };

  @media(min-width:992px+1px){
    .NewBlogCard{
        width:50%;
    }
  }


BlogCard.js
import React from "react";
import { dumplogs } from "./Utils";
import classes from "./BlogCard.module.css";
const BlogCard = (properties) => {
  dumplogs(properties);
  return (
    <div className={classes.NewBlogCard}>
      <h3>{properties.title}</h3>
      <p>{properties.description} </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogCard;

App.js
//import "./App.css";
import BlogCard from "./BlogCard";
import { isArrayEmpty } from "./Utils";
import classes from "./BlogCard.module.css";
function App() {
  const blogArr = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Blog Title 1",
      description:
        "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Blog Title 2",
      description:
        "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Blog Title 3",
      description:
        "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor",
    },
  ];

  const blogCards = isArrayEmpty(blogArr)
    ? []
    : blogArr.map((item, pos) => {
        console.log(item);

        return (
          <BlogCard
            key={pos}
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            id={item.id}
          />
          //<div className="BlogCard" key={item.id}>
          //<h3>{item.title}</h3>
          // <p>{item.description} </p>
          // </div>
        );
      });

  return <div className="App">{blogCards}</div>;
}

export default App;


Utils.js
const isArrayEmpty = (arr) => {
  if (arr !== undefined && arr !== null && arr.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const dumplogs = (message) => {
  console.log(message);

  //sends it to a tool for tracking
};

export { isArrayEmpty, dumplogs };
```

Comment: Can you show a working example of your problem in jsfiddle

Comment: try replacing your media query with this -> @media(min-width:993px)

Comment: I tried using 993px instead of 992px but still nothing changes in the browser. Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you  upload your code to jsfiddle  so that someone can check what is the real issue.

Comment: I am struggling to add my code to jsfiddle because I have never worked with it before and this is my first time working with React as well. On jsfiddle after selecting Reactjs, there are only 4 boxes- a box for HTML, CSS and JavaScript and results. But my code has so many files already and I don't know which one to add where. I tried adding App.js as the HTML, BlogCard.module.css as the Css and BlogCard.js as the JavaScript plus other different combinations but it is not working

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-roentgen-54u1en?file=/src/App.js try this

Comment: I 'll put it in answer mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added your code in codesandBox and made some changes please check

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-roentgen-54u1en?file=/src/App.js

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your given code you have declared as

```
  @media(min-width:992px+1px){
    .NewBlogCard{
        width:50%;
    }
```

But in your question, you mentioned you need

@media(min-width:992px)

Please have a look at that and try to remove the +1px in the media query

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I did try adding +1px and still nothing changes in the browser. The three cards are still displaying full screen width instead of half screen. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the cards to be in 50% in all screens, then you have to add

```
.NewBlogCard {
    width:50%;
}
```

without any media query.

If you need the cards to be in 50% above some screensize only then, you have to use media queries. Please go through this link to learn more about [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .NewBlogCard {
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

If you are using chrome browser and changes are not affecting better to do a hard reload and clear cache.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Neither of those seem to do anything. I am not sure what I did wrong but its as if it is not picking up my code or class. The first part of my code in the BlogCards.module.css file works but anything I put after that is not working like the @media statement. I'm starting to think its not the statement that is wrong but something else that went wrong somewhere in all my code

Comment: @Lizzy Can you please upload the code in stackbliz and give the link?